# Giving the access to codecommit repositories

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codecommit

I want to give only one repo access to developer in AWS Codecommit .How we can give while creating the user in IAM

Answer (score 1):

to manage access to resources on AWS we use [IAM](https://aws.amazon.com/iam/), the same applies to CodeCommit.

from an user perspective, [policies and permissions in IAM](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies.html#policies_id-based) can be assigned to the user, group or role.

for example, to allow all CodeCommit actions in an speficic repository, you can use:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement" : [
    {
      "Effect" : "Allow",
      "Action" : [
        "codecommit:*"
      ],
      "Resource" : "arn:aws:codecommit:us-east-2:111111111111:MyDemoRepo"
    }
  ]
}
```

this policy can be attached to an user, group or role.

for reference, you can learn more details in CodeCommit documentation:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/auth-and-access-control.html#managing-access-resources